# Create a reusable function where signup process selects each option during user registration

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am trying to create reusable function for login scenario where the user is given an option to select the choice of their department to curate the content. Only one option can be selected per one registration. I have created a file for just the locators and using cypress to return the first indexed item. I am calling the test in the main spec. This login function has multiple options to choose from and I have  added all the options in Json file in teamSelector.js. How do I make this teamSelector.js reusable fun? I don't want to specify the index in this file but call in my loginTest.js file with an ability to call all the available ID's from Json file.

loginTest.js file code below

```
import emailSignup from './emailsignup'
import teamSelector from './teamSelector'

{/* <reference types = "cypress" /> */}
const {commands} = require('../support/commands')

const { Input } = require("@angular/core")
const { wrap } = require("module")
const { isExportSpecifier } = require("typescript")



describe('our first suite', () => {

    const signup = new emailSignup()
    const signindepartment = new teamSelector()


    it('first test', () => {
        cy.visit('/')
        signup.signupforfreelink().click()
        // cy.get('a[data-tracking-name="Sign up for free"]').click()
        cy.get('.flex').should('contain',"Create your free account")
        cy.get('[for="emailSignup"]').should('contain',"Work email")
        signup.email()
        signup.continuebtn()
        signup.firstandlastname()
        signup.password()
        signup.signInButton()
        signup.alertsignup()
        signup.closealert()
        signindepartment.loginselectors()

})

})
```

teamSelector.js

```
class teamSelector {
```

loginselectors() {
return cy.get('.flex').find('[type="checkbox"]').then(userselection => {

```
    // const department = {
    //         "mar": "Marketing",
    //         "prod": "Product & Design",
    //         "eng": "Engineering",
    //         "supp": "IT & Support",
    //         "oper": "Operations",
    //         "acctmgnt": "Sales & Account Mgmt.",
    //         "hr": "HR & Legal",
    //         "creative": "Creative Production",
    //         "customerservice": "Customer Service",
    //         "fin": "Finance",
    //         "manfact":"Manufacturing",
    //         "other": "Other / Personal"
    //      }

    cy.wrap(userselection)
    .first()
    .check({force:true})
    .should('be.checked')

})
```

}

}

export default teamSelector

Comment: `loginselectors` function is not called during the test.

Comment: Yes, realized it right after I posted and updated the code. I am looking for a way to read values from Json file and use it in the test to call the indexed item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably best to pass the index into the method

```js
signindepartment.loginselectors(2)

// or pass in the code

signindepartment.loginselectors('eng')
```

```js
loginselectors(indexOrCode) {

  const departments = {
    "mar": "Marketing",             // index 0
    "prod": "Product & Design",     // index 1
    "eng": "Engineering",           // index 2
    ...
  }

  let dept;
  if (typeof indexOrCode === 'number') {
    dept = department[Object.keys(department)[indexOrCode]]
  } else {
    dept = departments[indexOrCode]
  }

  const deptSelector = `[value="${dept}"]`; // NOTE must use backticks
                                            // to insert dept into selector
  cy.get('[type="checkbox"]' + deptSelector]
    .check({force:true});                   // {force:true} if hidden
}
```

This presumes there's only one set of Department checkboxes on the page.

If you get an error saying "check failed because multiple element selected" then the presumption is wrong, and you need to look in the HTML for a unique parent selector to add before the `.check()`.

Comment: <div class="flex flex-wrap mt2"><div class="pr1 pb1 border-box xs-col-12"><div class="relative"><input id="Marketing" type="checkbox" class="absolute all-0 col-12 focus-visible appearance-none border-none background-none unround css-1srmem5" name="" value="Marketing"><label class="flex items-center rounded-big relative no-user-select heading-size-small strong white border border-darken3 darken1-hover text-dark pointer css-1j1shlp" for="Marketing"><div class="flex items-center">Marketing</div></label></div></div><div class="pr1 pb1 border-box xs-col-12"><div class="relative">

Comment: not able to add it in the main content. Here is the html. It has both ID and value but it is hidden

Comment: It has lengthy html but pretty much everything  has ID and  type. Thanks for your help

Comment: It looks ok, can use either `[value="${dept}"]` or `[id="${dept}"]` but `contains('.flex')` is not useful, can just drop it I think. Will update the code.

Comment: Small typo in the else statement, it should be department. Thanks for the help. Just tested the code and it works.